# What am I missing to make this show in 1 responsive column on phone?

Tags: responsive-design

At http://sallymilo.com/aem/, when I move my browser narrower, this template narrows to one column as I want. On my phone, however, I'm just seeing the whole template on one screen. I'm quite new to responsive design, so I must be missing something obvious to those of you who know better than I. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy fix, you need to have a viewport meta tag in the head of your page, without this the default behaviour of mobile devices is to scale your page to fit the screen.

Here's a starting suggestion:

```
<head>
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
...
</head>
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/ has more details on some of the properties you can set within the meta tag.

Comment: Thanks so much - I'm finally figuring out this responsive stuff and knew I was missing something obvious! Works as desired now!

Comment: Thanks @SallySlomzenskiMilo, good luck exploring responsive design!